# Extract text from one iteration of top

Tags: shell-script, awk, top

I want to execute the top command from my bash script

the problem is that usually when I type the top command on the console , I exit by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

but how to exit from `top` when I run the `top` command from my bash script ?

for example how to print the free memory from top in bash ?

I do the following but command not return value as I am explained

```
 top | grep Mem: | awk '{print $6" "$7}'
```

when I run the top from the console:

```
  top

  top - 17:55:24 up 20 days,  8:05,  3 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.08, 0.04
  Tasks:  93 total,   1 running,  92 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
  Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  3.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.2%id,  0.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
  Mem:   2075516k total,  1731156k used,   344360k free,   373308k buffers
  Swap:  4192924k total,       76k used,  4192848k free,  1130448k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+       COMMAND                                                               
   1 root      15   0  2072  656  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.36 init     
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: what about using the "free" command, instead of top?

Comment: I dont have free command on my linux box machine - sorry

Comment: `top -n1` will run just one iteration.

Comment: you can get the some of the info using `vmstat` command or looking directly into `/proc/meminfo`. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: `top -bn1` will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
top -bn1 | awk '$1=="Mem:" {print $6" "$7}'
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04, because the relevant line in the `top` output starts with `KiB Mem:   ` and so all positional params would need to be incremented.

Comment: This solution is strictly designed for OP question and his output of `top`. In your top version (BTW and mine too) just change it a little bit: `top -bn1 | awk '$2=="Mem:" {print $6" "$7}'`. You may need to change column numbers as well.

Answer (score 2):

@jimmij's answer is good from the `top` options point of view, though it looks like the format of the output from `top` can't be relied upon in a portable manner.

You mention you don't have the `free` utility, but this is just a wrapper around the `/proc/meminfo` interface, which you almost certainly do have.  Why not just get the information you need directly from the horses mouth (the kernel):

```
$ grep MemFree: /proc/meminfo
MemFree:           75916 kB
$
```

Or if you want it formatted as a single number by `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=="MemFree:" {print $2}' < /proc/meminfo
74320
$
```